# Objective-c How to load a UIViewController in synchronous way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, synchronous

my main application view load a UIVIewController for showing a disclaimer, user can or not accept, in a modal way.

The disclaimer UIVIewController has 2 buttons, 'agree' and 'disagree'.
If user clicks on 'disagree' the application close itself.
If user clicks on 'agree' the disclaimer UIVIewController close itself and the main application goes on.

The problem is that when i load the disclaimer UIViewController the main application goes on and not wait until the disclaimer UIViewController is discmissed.

There is a way to open a modal UIViewController in a 'synchronous way'?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to make your disclaimer view controller the `rootViewController` of your app and get it to load the subsequent views in case the user accepts its conditions of use.

Comment: Why don't you chain 2 ViewControllers? The first ViewController can show the disclaimer. If the user "agree"s, the second ViewController can load.

Comment: If you're using a navigation controller, push your main view and then push the disclaimer view, without showing the main view.  Pop the disclaimer if accepted.

Answer (score 1):

so I am assuming that in your application delegate in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method you have a viewController whos view is automatically added to the window. Well inside the viewController class in the -(void)viewDidLoad method you should allocate the disclaimer controller and present it modally using

```
[self presendModalViewController:my_disclaimer animate:YES];
```

This will cause the controller to slide up in front of everything. If the user clicks no then simply leave that modal controller display locking them out of the application.

so the code inside your viewController -(void)viewDidLoad method should read

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
//Alocate memory
MyCustomController *controller = [[MyCustomController alloc] initWithWhatever:arguements_to_get_controller_setup];
//present controller
[self presentModalViewController:controller animate:YES];

}
```